# Xkill command renders wine useless

Tags: wine, xkill

I play Skyrim on a Ubuntu 16.04. Every once in a while the game freezes so I searched online for a solution. I discovered the Xkill command from the terminal. When I use this command, Wine won't open any more programs, even those not Skyrim. If you could figure out a solution for this, please answer. Also if you could figure out why my Skyrim keeps freezing I would be very happy.

Comment: What is the command line that you used and what is your system. Also please only ask one question per post.

Comment: All I type is 'xkill' and click on my frozen game. What do you mean by system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xkill command is a little bit primitive, although sometimes useful.

Much more sophisticated is the `pkill` command ([pkill man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pkill.1.html)).

For example, shut down all Firefox browser instances can be done with :

```
pkill firef
```

(Yes, only the relevant part of the application command is needed)

Shut down all commands running by user Dominico :

```
sudo pkill -u dominico
```

Sometimes pkill will not work when an application is called in a script or through an interpreter, e.g. bash or python here. In that case you can consider shutting down the "program helper" which starts the other program.

Note : Beware, using pkill command to kill bash processes would be very counter productive on your local computer as all your login processes might be killed, and it would be much worse on a server!

Comment: how do I figure out the name of the program

Comment: Did you try : pkill skyrim   or pkill wine when it froze again ? The ps auxw|less command can also help ?

Comment: Well, I just typed pkill wine and the game froze. I tried pkill skyrim and pkill wineprogramloader (because that is what shows up on the sidebar).

Comment: I just discovered that if I use the pkill command and then the xkill command, I can get back on without having to restart my computer.